# Change window size of browser for test purpose

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, window

In order to test a website's (responsive) appearance with different screen resolutions I want to programmatically start browsers with a certain window size to simulate these screen sizes.

The best thing would be to change the window size while the browser is already running, although I read that the window.resizeTo() function does not work in modern browsers anymore. 
I am in the context of a browser extension so I could also use the capabilities of that. However, I could not find anything here that suits my needs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK.

A not-very-satisfying solution would be starting the browser with a fixed determined screen size (although I don't know how that works, as at least Firefox has no such start parameters - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-new-window_URL).

There must be a way to control the size of a window I guess. I also tried to wrap a  around a given website's body with style width and height properties, but the website behaves completely different compared to being accessed with that window size.

I am on a Unix system (Mac OS X Yosemite).

**edit**

I ended up solving the problem as follows:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
function showPage(tab) {
    var {
        viewFor
    } = require("sdk/view/core");
    var win = viewFor(require("sdk/windows").browserWindows[0]);
    win.resizeTo(dimension.width, dimension.height);
    tab.on("pageshow", attachScript);
    tabs.removeListener('open', showPage);
}
tabs.on('open', showPage);
```

Comment: You can open a new window and specify its size.

Comment: Have you tried the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) add-on?

Comment: Opening a new window could be actually possible. I will try that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several *possible* solutions:

1. Open `about:config` and make sure `dom.disable_window_move_resize` is set to `false`. Now you are able to resize Pop-up windows:

   ```
   var myWindow = window.open("about:blank", "SomeName", "width=300,height=300");
   myWindow.resizeTo(200, 400);
   ```
2. Use an `<iframe>` and resize it.
3. Probably the best way: Use `window.resizeTo(400, 500)` within an Add-on. When I try to run this line in the normal "Web Console" that belongs to a web page it doesn't work. But it works when using the "Browser Toolbox" that belongs to the whole browser chrome. I think an Add-on could have those privileges too.

   **Update:** I created a working example:

   ```
   var buttons        = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
       browserWindows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
       viewFor        = require("sdk/view/core");

   buttons.ActionButton({
       id: "resize-window",
       label: "Resize Window",
       icon: {
           "16": "./icon-16.png",
           "32": "./icon-32.png",
           "64": "./icon-64.png"
       },
       onClick: handleClick
   });

   function handleClick(state) {
       var win = viewFor(browserWindows[0]);
       win.resizeTo(500, 500);
   }
   ```
4. There is an "Responsive Design View" and also commands for use within the "Developer Toolbar" (`resize to 480 800`) but I don't know how they can be triggered from outside :-/.
5. Add-ons like "Web Developer" are able to resize the window. You can look at their solution: https://github.com/chrispederick/web-developer/
6. Add the command line arguments `-width` and `-height` while starting Firefox or opening a new window.

Probably not all solutions fit to your test environment, but hopefully at least one of them does ;).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not very robust, since you will have to edit the script every time a new item is added to your Tools menu. Nor is it helpful for the average user, as it is requires you to edit some Python code. That being said, it works, and it might be useful for people who don't want to install an add-on.

1. Install xdotool: ~$ sudo apt install xdotool
2. Install python-gtk2 and python-wnck: ~$ sudo apt install python-gtk2 python-wnck
3. Place the following script wherever you like to store your scripts:

   ```
   import gtk
   from random import randint
   import subprocess
   import time
   import wnck

   def main():

   firefox = subprocess.Popen(['firefox'])

   # start with a maximized screen. If this is undesired,
   # use code on lines 45 - end, disregaurding the rest 
   sentinal = True
   while sentinal:

       screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

       while gtk.events_pending():

           gtk.main_iteration()

       windows = screen.get_windows()

       for w in windows:

           if w.get_pid() == firefox.pid:

               w.maximize()
               sentinal = False

       time.sleep(1)


   # click the 'Tools' menu in Firefox
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'mousemove', '--sync', '300', '80'])
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'click', '1'])
   time.sleep(1)

   # hover over 'Web Developer' sub-menu
   # (i.e. Tools -> Web Developer)
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'mousemove_relative', '--sync', '0', '180'])
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'click', '1'])

   # click the responsive design view sub-menu
   # (i.e. Tools -> Web Developer -> Responsive Design View)
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'mousemove_relative', '--sync', '300', '0'])
   time.sleep(1)
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'mousemove_relative', '--sync', '0', '300'])
   time.sleep(1)
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'click', '1'])

   # set your window size here
   y = ['1280x600']

   choice = y[0]

   # click the uri bar
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'mousemove', '--sync', '110', '144'])
   time.sleep(1)
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'click', '1'])

   # tab to the drop-down resolution menu
   for i in range(0, 3):

       subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'key', 'Tab'])

   # erase whatever is in the resolution menue by default
   for j in range(0, 15):

       subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'key', 'BackSpace'])

   # enter a random (standardized) screen resolution
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'type',  choice])
   subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'key', 'Return'])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
4. Anywhere in the code you see (['xdotool', ... 'integer', 'integer']), you need to map these points to points on your Firefox window. In other words, you are automating the task of opening a window with a certain screen size, using Tools --> Responsive Web Developer -> The Dropdown Box that you can enter a window size in, etc. There are various tools to get the coordinates of your mouse. I wrote this a while back, so I do not remember what I used. Google is your friend.
5. You can then run the script every time you want to open Firefox with a certain window size. Additionally, you can create a .desktop shortcut to launch Firefox with this script. It would be easy to modify this code a little bit to allow command line arguments to specify other screen sizes, or simply create multiple scripts for each screen size.

Comment: Hmm, I did not realize the question was for Mac. This works on Ubuntu, but I am not sure about Mac.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you tried this icon? You can choose whatever device you want, or just control de width and height of the viewport.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution is only available in Chrome and not Firefox (as per the tags and original question). Definitely a good solution if testing in Chrome is an option, though!

Comment: As I said I want to do this programmatically. It would be good if this could be triggered by an extension via API or something. It doesn't help if somebody needs to click something manually.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I have found that is close to the resizing of the chrome window is to use a chrome extension that can resize the window. The actual extension command is 
`chrome.windows.update(...)`

[See This](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

But I am not sure this is what you are looking for.
If it still interests you there are at least 2 extensions that can do this, that I have seen try [this.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal)

Comment: I don't really have the problem in Chrome as I can use a webview which I can specify the dimension of. Firefox is more of a problem :-/